# tmux: keyboard cursor disappears after leaving scroll mode

Tags: bash, tmux

I'm using tmux on a CentOS host machine. Whenever I leave scroll mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>[</kbd> to enter, <kbd>q</kbd> to leave), my keyboard cursor disappears and I find it difficult to type. Is it a known bug or are there ways to get the cursor back without restarting the session?

Comment: The cursor is probably handled by your terminal emulator. What software is it? Does the problem remain after you attach to the same session from another terminal? Do not detach the first terminal. Are two cursors missing? or one? Check different terminal emulators. What happens? Please [edit] the question and add this information.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have a similar problem in `tmux`.  Sometimes the cursor disappears in one window; but the other windows have a flashing cursor.

I found this: https://github.com/tj/git-extras/issues/538#issuecomment-222312367

TL;DR:

```
   tput cnorm
```

fixes it, in that window.  Still don't know what causes it, or how to prevent it.

Answer (score 3):

For me `reset` and two times <kbd>Enter</kbd> does it and is easier to remember then `tput cnorm`.